# User Authentication Using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, angularjs

I found the article from angularcode
and [this link](http://www.angularcode.com/user-authentication-using-angularjs-php-mysql/) is helpful.
But I have some problem with my webpage structure that doesn't want to have the `div` tag for containing `data-ng-view` attribute. How do I get data, but no this `div` tag?

This is some code from the tutorial:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            title: 'Login',
            templateUrl: '/login.php',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
            .when('/logout', {
                title: 'Logout',
                templateUrl: '/login.php',
                controller: 'logoutCtrl'
            })
            .when('/signup', {
                title: 'Signup',
                templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
            })
            .when('/dashboard', {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                templateUrl: '/dashboard.php',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
            })
            .when('/', {
                title: 'Login',
                templateUrl: '/login.php',
                controller: 'authCtrl',
                role: '0'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });
  }])
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data) {
        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            Data.get('session').then(function (results) {
                if (results.uid) {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    $rootScope.uid = results.uid;
                    $rootScope.name = results.name;
                    $rootScope.email = results.email;
                } else {
                    var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
                    if (nextUrl == '/signup' || nextUrl == '/login') {

                    } else {
                        $location.path("/login");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I want to separate the structure for each page. What's any method to link to other page instead show like `templateURL` on `data-ng-view` but the function of user authentication session still work?

---

**UPDATE**

This is my code from my project
Note that I have try `templateURL` both .html and .php are the same result.

**index.php**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" data-ng-view="" id="ng-view"></div>

<toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000}"></toaster-container>

<!-- authentification script -->
<script src="/pooh/dist/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/pooh/dist/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="/pooh/dist/js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/pooh/dist/js/toaster.js"></script>
<script src="/pooh/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="/pooh/app/data.js"></script>
<script src="/pooh/app/directives.js"></script>
<script src="/pooh/app/authCtrl.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            title: 'Login',
            templateUrl: '/pooh/login.php',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
            .when('/logout', {
                title: 'Logout',
                templateUrl: '/pooh/login.php',
                controller: 'logoutCtrl'
            })
            .when('/signup', {
                title: 'Signup',
                templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
            })
            .when('/dashboard', {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                templateUrl: '/pooh/dashboard.php',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
            })
            .when('/', {
                title: 'Login',
                templateUrl: '/pooh/login.php',
                controller: 'authCtrl',
                role: '0'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });
  }])
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data) {
        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            Data.get('session').then(function (results) {
                if (results.uid) {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    $rootScope.uid = results.uid;
                    $rootScope.name = results.name;
                    $rootScope.email = results.email;
                } else {
                    var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
                    if (nextUrl == '/signup' || nextUrl == '/login') {

                    } else {
                        $location.path("/login");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**login.php**

```
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pooh/head.php');?>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="/pooh/index.php"><b>Pooh</b>Furniture</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="login-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input ng-model="login.email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input ng-model="login.password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="checkbox icheck">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button ng-click="doLogin(login)" data-ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>

    <a class="hidden" href="#">I forgot my password</a><br>

  </div>
  <!-- /.login-box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->

<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script src="/pooh/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="/pooh/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- iCheck 1.0.1 -->
<script src="/pooh/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('input').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
      increaseArea: '20%' // optional
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**dashboard.php**

```
<?php 
//check if already logged in move to home page
//if logged in redirect to members page
//if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: login.php'); } 
?>
<?php $page = 'summary'; ?>
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pooh/header.php');?>
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pooh/sidebar.php');?>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Dashboard
                <small>Overall information</small>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Level</a></li>
        <li class="active">Here</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

      <!-- Your Page Content Here -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pooh/footer.php');?>
```

**some of code from header.php**

to show that the `body` tag has class attribute

```
<body class="hold-transition fixed skin-blue sidebar-mini">
```

Comment: you must always include file html in your templateUrl

Comment: That's work, thank you. I have other problem that all link are go to /# (that is go to log in page). It seems javascript not working or I don't know what is the problem occur from?

Comment: do you have an error when you open console and reload your page ? All your script are loaded ? Do you have renamed your templateUrl by .html in your app.js and files ? I think that you can create a new issue on stackoverflow and paste your code html, js and the path of all

Comment: No any error, all script are loaded.
Note that i have checked again html,head,body tag in templateURL are disappear when load to data-ng-view. how I fix this?

Comment: I have update my project code above.